# R shiny not taking user input correctly

Tags: r, shiny

Very basic R shiny issue Im sure. I want to run a linear regression on a toy dataset, use that to predict corresponding values based on used input, and plot a line to the regression line from  the given and predicted values.

When I run this, I get the error: 
Listening on http://XXX
Warning: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 6 rows
Error in segments(newData, 0, newData, newData.pred, col = "red") :
  invalid first argument

SO I realise it's how I'm handling the user input. I jsut want to take the numeric value they give, feed it to predict.lm and draw the resultant line. Id like text too if possible to give the predict.lm output.

ui.R

```
 library(shiny)
 (pageWithSidebar(
 headerPanel('Predicty'),
sidebarPanel
(
numericInput('clusters', 'Absorbance', 0.1, min = 0, max = 100, step = 0.00001)
),
mainPanel
(
  plotOutput('plot1')
)
))
```

server.R

```
 library(shiny)

##  Initial data and linear regression. 
conc <- c(.25, .5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5) 
abs <- c(.332, .631, .972, 1.201, 1.584, 1.912) 
results <- data.frame(abs,conc) 
abss <- lm(conc~abs, data = results)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({


 newData.in <- reactive({
inFile <- input$clusters
inFile
 })

 newData <- data.frame(newData.in()) 
newData.pred <- predict.lm(abss, newData) 

plot(abs,conc) 
abline(abss)

segments(newData , 0, newData, newData.pred, col = "red")
 # segments(0, newData.pred[i], clusters()$centers, newData.pred[i], col = i)

  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `reactive` in your `renderPlot`, the function is already `reactive`.

`predict.lm` did not find any column names `abs` in your input which throws the first warning.

`segments` takes coordinates as arguments, you inputed a `data.frame` which explains the second error.

You could do:

```
 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({   
    newData <- data.frame(abs=input$clusters) 
    newData.pred <- predict.lm(abss, newData) 
    abline(abss)   
    segments(newData$abs , 0, newData$abs, newData.pred, col = "red")

  })
```

Also, you might want to change the `xlim` of your plot or the start value for your input because `0.1` is not on the plot